# How to get Response Body from servletResponse in Spring Boot Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to get `Response Body` from `ServletResponse` to make a hash signature from it before passing to the client. I couldn't get the way to do it. For getting the request body from `ServletRequest`  I have implemented like the following:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.servlet.ReadListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper{

    private final String body;
     
    public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException 
    {
        //So that other request method behave just like before
        super(request);
         
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                    stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        //Store request pody content in 'body' variable 
        body = stringBuilder.toString();
    }
 
    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
        ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
            public int read() throws IOException {
                return byteArrayInputStream.read();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isFinished() {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isReady() {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {

                
            }
        };
        return servletInputStream;
    }
 
    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
    }
 
    //Use this method to read the request body N times
    public String getBody() {
        return this.body;
    }
}
```

How can I do similar to `ServletResponse`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I implemented the `ContentCachingResponseWrapper` in the Filter to get response body from `ServletResponse` as follow:

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseCacheWrapperObject = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, responseCacheWrapperObject);

        byte[] responseArray = responseCacheWrapperObject.getContentAsByteArray();
        String responseStr = new String(responseArray, responseCacheWrapperObject.getCharacterEncoding());
        //....use responsestr to make the signature

        responseCacheWrapperObject.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you implemented `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`, and why we need `responseCacheWrapperObject.copyBodyToResponse();`?

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingResponseWrapper.html) @Milena T, you can wrap the response on cache and after get a array bytes. If you don't use copyBodyToResponse, you body response is null, because you use ContentCachingResponseWrapper in filterChain.doFilter instead of HttpServletResponse, and you need to recovery this or something like that.

Answer (score -2):

try to use something like:

```
public void handleException(Throwable e, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, int status) {
    CustomErrorResponseException errorResponse = new CustomErrorResponseException();

    errorResponse.setError(e.getClass().getSimpleName());
    errorResponse.setStatus(status);
    errorResponse.setMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    errorResponse.setPath(request.getRequestURI());
    errorResponse.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now().toString());

    response.setStatus(status);
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    try {
        response.getWriter().write(jsonbMapper.serialize(errorResponse));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

And in filter just pass Exception, request, response and status you want to.